# File upload not working in ASP.NET When Deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code is working fine on localhost but when I try to run this code in server its not working..can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
private void SaveFileToDatabase(string filePath)
    {
        String strConnection = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EkkiDB;Integrated Security=TRUE";

        String excelConnString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0\"", filePath);
        //Create Connection to Excel work book 
        using (OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnString))
        {
            //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel 
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [SurveyDate],[DealerName],[Model],[HP],[Quantity],[ID] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection))
            {
                excelConnection.Open();
                using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
                    {
                        //Give your Destination table name 
                        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Import_Survey";
                        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private string GetLocalFilePath( FileUpload fileUploadControl)
    {

        //string filePath = Server.MapPath(fileUploadControl.FileName);
       // string filePath = Path.Combine(saveDirectory);
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/xl/") + Path.GetFileName(fileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);
        fileUploadControl.SaveAs(filePath);

        return filePath;

    }
```

Comment: "Not working", can you be more descriptive?  Is your code executing?

Comment: From where you are calling `GetLocalFilePath`? have you tried to debug your code? what is the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270419/file-uploads-not-working-when-deployed-to-server#Sam

Answer (score 0):

Where is your destination directory? If it's not under IIS control check that your anonymous user account has write access to it.